# Distinguish quotation mark (") from backslash and quotation mark (\")

Tags: regex, r, url

This is a simplified version of an issue I am trying to solve.
So, try not to hack answer it :)

In R, by default

```
'"' == '\"'
```

Therefore, when I use

```
URLencode('\"')
URLencode('"')
```

I got the same result:  `%22`

However, what I really want is

`%5C%22` and `%22` respectively for the above two commands.

The goal is to encode a string such as `'parse "I am * \"good\"" as adj'` into a URL string

```
parse%20%22I%20am%20*%20%5C%22good%5C%22%22%20as%20adj
```

Any ideas?

========== update =====

Given the confusions from the above question. I would like to further clarify that:
I understand `R` treats `'\"'` as `'"'`. 
But I want `R` to automatically, rather than me **manually**,  convert a **user's** string input of `'\"'` to `'\\\"'` while treating a input string of `'"'` as `'"'` or `'\"'`, which are equivalent anyway.

Comment: maybe `URLencode('\\"')`?

Comment: It sounds like you think there is a slash in the first string. There is not. There is just a character escape. To get a literal slash, you need to escape the slash. `URLencode('\\\"')` will return `"%5C%22"`. note that `nchar('\\\"')==2` while `nchar('\"')==1`. "\" acts as an escape the same way in both single and double quoted strings so `URLencode("\\\"")` and `URLencode('\\\"')` are the same.

Comment: Just to augment what @MrFlick said, you can see that `\"` is treated as exactly the same string as `"` by trying this: `identical('"', '\"')`.

Comment: @MrFlick, your point is almost exactly my point. My currently solution is indeed manually modify the input string form '\"' to '\\\"'. But as I stated in the question, I would like R to distinguish a input string of '\"' from a input string of '"'. Again, they are inputs, I do not want to manually add two more slashes. I want R to add two more slashes to '\"', but not to '"'

Comment: Where is the string coming from? Are you importing it into R? Are you copy/pasting? You cannot change the R parser to make those two things different; they are exactly identical.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, for your quick response. The input is from a shiny text input box. And indeed, I also believe R thinks them identical. So, I am trying my luck here see if anyone else have a solution.

Comment: If you are getting data from a shiny text box, then shiny should translate those for your differently. Try: `runApp(list(ui=mainPanel(textInput("userin", "input"), textOutput("userout")),server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {output$userout<- renderText({URLencode(input$userin)})})))`. If `shiny` is involved, you should make that clear in your question. It seems like you are leaving out import info.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying it in the question. But I was originally really looking for a generic solution such that I can take the input from anywhere, such as  a text file, clipboard, or shiny. Thanks again.

Comment: If you use any function to read data into R from a text file or clipboard, R will distinguish between the two values and do the proper escaping automatically. Same goes for Shiny. The rules of strings in R code is different than what's allows in raw data.

Answer (score 1):

The R string literals treat a backslash as an escaping symbol. If you write `\"`, the backslash is just escaping a `"`, but since it is not a valid escape sequence, the backslash is ignored.

To write a literal backslash, use `\\`, double backslashes.

```
URLencode('\\"') 
## => "%5c%22"
URLencode('"')
## => "%22"
URLencode('parse "I am * \\"good\\"" as adj')
## => "parse%20%22I%20am%20*%20%5c%22good%5c%22%22%20as%20adj"
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/10GlsH)

Comment: Thanks, @stribizhev, I am currently indeed manually changing a input of '\"' into '\\\"' so that URLencode works as I want. But, that is not sustainable. I want to write a function such that it takes a user input and correctly parse the input `'"' ` into `%22`, and parse the user input `'\"'` into `%5c%22`